# How to create syntax highlighting rule

Tags: monaco-editor

I'm trying out monaco editor and I'm having real difficulty understanding how to create my own rule for syntax highlighting. (I'd really appreciate it if you had a resource that explains how to create rules)

I'm starting with the simple stuff:

- I'd like to add a special color for my variable at declaration. ie: `a = 12`, having color on `a`
- Add a special color for builtins functions. ie: `builtin(a, b)`, having color on `builtin`

I'm using https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/monarch.html to try the rule in real-time
here is my syntax definition

```
// Create your own language definition here
// You can safely look at other samples without losing modifications.
// Modifications are not saved on browser refresh/close though -- copy often!
return {
  defaultToken: '',
    tokenPostfix: '.ds',

    keywords: [
        'do', 'then', 'end', 'function', 'if', 'else', 'return', 'continue', 'break', 'for',
    'while', 'to', 'until', 'in', 'static', 'step', 'delete', 'true', 'false'
    ],

  builtins: [
    'print', 'builtin'
  ],

    operators: [
        '=', '>', '<', '!', '?', ':', '==', '<=', '>=', '!=',
    '&&', '||', '++', '--', '**', '+', '-', '*', '/', '%',
    '<<', '>>', '+=', '-=', '*=', '/=', '%=',
    ],

    // we include these common regular expressions
    symbols: /[=><!~?:&|+\-*\/\^%]+/,
    escapes: /\\(?:[abfnrtv\\"']|x[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}|u[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}|U[0-9A-Fa-f]{8})/,

    // The main tokenizer for our languages
    tokenizer: {
        root: [
            // My attempt for variable syntax colorization
      ["^[a-zA-Z_]+(?=\s*=)", 'variable.name' ],
      // identifiers and keywords
            [
                /[a-zA-Z_]\w*/,
                {
                    cases: {
                        '@keywords': { token: 'keyword.$0' },
            // My attempt for builtins syntax colorizatio
            '@builtins': 'predefined',
                        '@default': 'identifier'
                    }
                }
            ],
            // whitespace
            { include: '@whitespace' },
            // delimiters and operators
            [/[{}()\[\]]/, '@brackets'],
            [
                /@symbols/,
                {
                    cases: {
                        '@operators': 'delimiter',
                        '@default': ''
                    }
                }
            ],

            // numbers
            [/\d*\.\d+([eE][\-+]?\d+)?/, 'number.float'],
            [/0[xX][0-9a-fA-F_]*[0-9a-fA-F]/, 'number.hex'],
            [/\d+?/, 'number'],

            // delimiter: after number because of .\d floats
            [/[;,.]/, 'delimiter'],

            // strings: recover on non-terminated strings
            [/"([^"\\]|\\.)*$/, 'string.invalid'], // non-teminated string
            [/'([^'\\]|\\.)*$/, 'string.invalid'], // non-teminated string
            [/"/, 'string', '@string."'],
            [/'/, 'string', "@string.'"]
        ],
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly then you cannot do what you want with a syntax highlighter. What you want is semantic highlighting.

Syntax is about the structure of a language. It determines what is an identifier, what is a number, a string etc.

Semantic gives meaning to things, for instance **which** identifier is a variable, which is a class name or another type etc.

Monarch is a declarative tokenizer, a tool that assigns token values to specific parts of text. How to find which part of the text gets which token value is declared in the `tokenizer` field.

But you cannot find semantic from syntax rules. Instead you would have to parse the input and decide from the parse tree/syntax tree which role a symbol plays in the input.

Comment: I see, thank you for your detailed explanation :)